# ASP.NET exclude folder from publishing , but keep files on server

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ftp, publish

I have an old ASP.NET website. need to exclude folder from publishing , but keep that folder on server.

Folder: img contains many images marked as "content"
Publish method: FTP
In setting I have "Delete all existing file prior to publish" UNCHECKED, yet files are still being when publish.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio go to the Solution Explorer, right-click on the file you do not want to copy and then click on properties.  Set the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Do not copy."